# What is the best way to make a private git repository using the AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying AWS cloud solutions and want to make a privat git repository, but there are  multipe ways of doing this: on `Ec2 Instence`, by `CodeCommit`  or any other ways of doing this. Any suggestion are well appreciated.

Comment: A git repository is just a directory on some filesystem somewhere. All you need for a "remote" is SSH access.  If you need something more sophisticated (multiple-user access with permissions), you could look at something like bitbucket or stash.

Comment: You can install [GitLab Community Edition](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) on your EC2 instance at no cost and host your private repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean codecommit, not codedeploy:

http://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/

> AWS CodeCommit is a secure, highly scalable, managed source control
>   service that hosts private Git repositories. AWS CodeCommit eliminates
>   the need for you to operate your own source control system or worry
>   about scaling its infrastructure. You can use AWS CodeCommit to store
>   anything from code to binaries, and it works seamlessly with your
>   existing Git tools.

If you want to be on AWS, and you are open to using codecommit, that is going to be your safest, easiest, cheapest and most reliable option.

You can certainly run it on an EC2 instance, but then you need to have that instance running all the time, and you need to back it up, and possibly have a hot spare ready to go in case your first goes down...

Or, for a few pennies a day you can let AWS handle all that for you.